# EC2 ssh Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, permission-denied

I got this permission denied problem when I want to `ssh` to my `ec2` host. I tried existing solution `chmod 600 "My.pem"` but still didn't work. Here is my debug information:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.223.47.74 [54.223.47.74] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file My.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file My.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 54.223.47.74:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:tfjxcE5kePSv1cJK7SWBp/56kgm2DQkyPLSLZ4d73Io
debug1: Host '54.223.47.74' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tan/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: My.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: What are you setting as the SSH user? Does it match the user on the ec2 machine. It will probably be `ubuntu` or `root`

Comment: I think it should be root, the machine is redhat 7.1. I tried root and ec2-user to ssh, none of them succeeded.

Comment: post more verbose log. You can specify more `-v` options on commandline. Also check for the errors in server log, if you have web-console.

Comment: *Authenticating to 54.223.47.74:*`22` *as* `'root'`, ... *Found key in /Users/tan/.ssh/known_hosts:24*, ... *debug1: Roaming not allowed by server*.  It appears you are connecting as `root` and then attempting to authenticate as `you`.

Answer (score 204):

I resolved this issue in my centos machine by using command:

```
ssh -i <Your.pem> ec2-user@<YourServerIP>
```

It was about *userName* which was `ec2-user` in my case.

Referenced From: [AMAZONTroubleshooting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm)

Comment: Interesting, when closing connection, AWS itself returned
`Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".` which works.

Comment: oh nice. Now they have implemented that error log then. Earlier it was not there...

Comment: This helped me. It was the AWS suggested user id is **centos**, that was causing the issue. **ec2-user** is the right one. I did not get the message that @frmbelz did, BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the ec2-user tip.  It is extremely annoying that Amazon does not make  it clearer in their documentation what they mean by instance-username (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

Comment: aha! I had typed `ec2_user` instead of `ec2-user`  :P

Answer (score 33):

You can find default usernames of ec2 instances here:
https://alestic.com/2014/01/ec2-ssh-username/

But in case you want to find the username of your instance:
click on the Connect button to see the default username.

After finding the username, run this command, to ensure your key is not publicly viewable.

```
chmod 400 <private-key-file.pem>
```

Then Connect to your instance using its Public DNS or IP:

```
ssh -i <private-key-file.pem> ec2-user@<public ip>
```

Answer (score 26):

Solved by connecting with the user `centos` instead of `ec2-user`.

Comment: More generally, it's solved by using the _correct_ user for the AMI.  You happened to be using an AMI that enables centos, but not ec2-user.  You just have to look at the AMI documentation to know what's correct.  (And if there is no documentation, don't use that AMI.)

Answer (score 18):

I noticed each Linux instance launches with a default Linux system user account. This might be different from `ec2-user`, depending on your instance. You log in using following command where `DefaultUserName` stands for a username from the quote below.

```
ssh -i <Your.pem> <DefaultUserName>@<YourPublicServerIP>
```

> Each Linux instance launches with a default Linux system user account. The default user name is determined by the AMI that was specified when you launched the instance.
>
> - For **Amazon Linux 2** or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is **ec2-user**.
> - For a **CentOS** AMI, the user name is **centos**.
> - For a **Debian** AMI, the user name is **admin**.
> - For a **Fedora** AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **fedora**.
> - For a **RHEL** AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **root**.
> - For a **SUSE** AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **root**.
> - For an **Ubuntu** AMI, the user name is **ubuntu**.
> - Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from the username issue mentioned here, it can very well be an issue with.

- permissions on the instance
- public key on the instance not matching the public key you have available locally in your .pem file.
  The following link Method 1 resolved it for me. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/

For me it was the public key mismatch. and the is how I resolved it. I am on Mac which comes with an ssh-client.

You can get your local public key from your .pem file by running the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f /path_to_key_pair/my-key-pair.pem
```

On your instance navigate to your authorized_keys file which will typically be found here:

```
/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Add your public key to this file. Save and Done. That should do it.

Just a little context for why I ran into the issue. I had to create a new .pem file because I lost the one I downloaded when I launched the instance. For security reasons, this file cannot be downloaded again. As a I created a new .pem file, this created a new public key with it. This public key needs to be update manually on the instance as the authorized_keys file is still pointing to the old public key.

There is more formal 9 step process to get this sorted as well. See here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html

Answer (score 5):

Recently I went through this issue,
Accidently I have changed Home permission using, `chmod -R g+rw .`
it changed `.ssh` folder permission.

1. If nothing work out,
   Create Temp Instance on Amazon-EC2
2. Detach Your Server storage (Before that Down your source Machine)
3. Mount it as secondary storage in Temp Instance
4. Do below permission changes,

   **[ec2-user ~]$ chmod 600 mount_point/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys**

   **[ec2-user ~]$ chmod 700 mount_point/home/ec2-user/.ssh**

   **[ec2-user ~]$ chmod 700 mount_point/home/ec2-user**
5. Unmount your Source Disk from Temp Instance
6. Attach it back to source Machine
7. Now Use same command to login,

   ssh -i FileName.pem username@MachineIP

For More Details see this [AWS Trouble Shooting Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm)

Answer (score 2):

add user to `/etc/sshd_special_user`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and, in my case, the problem was the file "My.pem" should be created with the admin user

So, the solution was, first create the file "My.pem" with sudo and change the permison to 400

```
$ sudo su
$ sudo vim My.pem
  #paste the content

$ sudo vim chmod 400 My.pem

$ ssh -i My.pem user@host
  # Login ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are in the same directory where your key is there.
I had the same problem and figured out that it was the wrong directory form where I tried to connect

Answer (score 1):

```
cd .ssh
rm authorized_keys
```

file or edit and remove the saved key for the machine you are trying to access.

Change permissions on the key file with `chmod 400 keyname` (make sure `keyname` matches exactly as you have it on Amazon).

Try again with `ec2-user@IPaddress -i keypair.pem`

Answer (score 1):

On Mac:

```
cd ~/.ssh
sudo nano known_hosts
```

And delete the info of the host with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the same directory where you have your .pem file.

use command, chmod 0400 example.pem

then use command, ssh -i example.pem ec2-user@YOUR-IP

Comment: The -i option takes a path.  Your path needs to be correct, but you definitely don't need to be in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `ssh` command specifies the ec2 user:

```
# ec2 user is missing
ssh -i <identity_file.pem> <hostname>
```

```
# ec2 user is specified
ssh -i <identity_file.pem> ec2-user@<hostname>
```

Comment: ec2-user is added, but still getting the same

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in my case it was because I created a new key to connect from a different device. The key pairs only get added when you create a new instance, if you want to create a new key after the instance has been created you will have to add it manually.

You can follow this guide here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#identify-key-pair-specified-at-launch

or

1. `ssh` into the AWS instance using your old key pair
2. `cd` into the `~/.ssh` folder and
3. open `authorized_keys` file using `nano` or whatever you like
4. then go to you new `.pem` key pair and retrieve the public key using

   `ssh-keygen -y -f /path_to_key_pair/my-key-pair.pem`
5. copy the returned public key and paste it inside authorized_keys file below your other keys , save and exit.
6. `chmod 400 my-key-pair.pem` if you haven't already
7. Then you should be all good to connect using your new key pair.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to harneet singh's answer you can also change your ec2 instance user name from "ec2-user". navigate to EC2 instance->connect-> ec2InstanceConnect->user-name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, The default user name for your `EC2` instance is determined by the AMI that was specified when you launched the instance.

For `Amazon Linux 2` or the `Amazon Linux AMI`, the user name is `ec2-user`.

Therefore, you will need to use `ec2-user` when `SSH`.

Afterwards, grant file permissions via chmod in Linux. (Make sure you are in the same directory where you have your .pem file)

use command, `chmod 400 <Ur_Pem_File_Name>.pem`

Now use command, `ssh -i <Ur_Pem_File_Name>.pem ec2-user@<Public_IP_of_EC2>`

By doing the above, I was able to SSH into my EC2 via CLI.

Answer (score 1):

(*Several years later*) If you are using Centos you are likely to encounter this issue. They do change the default user as below

- Centos7 - centos
- Centos8 - cloud-user

Answer (score 0):

Check if selinux is blocking access to the file.

Try the following:

```
restorecon -r -vv .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and resolved by -

1. in Window machine , Save key into Pageant
   See https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/
2. and then in Putty select SSH->Auth-> Check "Allow Agent Forwarding" & put ppk file into "Private Key file for Authentication" .

Answer (score 0):

if you are connecting ec2 via ssh using your terminal (.zsh) on mac then you have to change the name from .pem to .cer in all the commands because on mac your downloaded key_pair file has an extension .cer,
otherwise, you can follow the commands same as given on aws.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-ssh-permission-denied-publickey
In the AWS EC2 console, click on the checkbox next to your instance's name, then click on Actions and select Connect. Click on the SSH client tab and copy the ssh command example.

Answer (score 0):

Even after running both commands

`chmod 400 key.pem`
`chmod 600 key.pem`

and trying command like this

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ec2-user@<public>.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I was getting the error "Permission denied (public key,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)."

when I changed the Public IP in command to public DNS it started working. If someone is facing an issue related to that, they can give it a try.

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-xx-x-xxx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

you can get the DNS name under server details and field name -> "Public IPv4 DNS"

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following command first:

```
eb ssh --setup (enviroment)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to run below commands for ssh to your ec2 host

```
ssh -i <user.pem> ec2-user@<public ip>
```

if have

```
WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          
Permissions 0644 for 'user.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

then run `chmod 0400 <user.pem>`

after run above command run    `ssh -i <user.pem> ec2-user@<public ip>`

Answer (score -3):

Soluction in terminal for error

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

```
ssh-keygen -f " ~/.ssh/known_hosts" -R xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

xx - ip host

http://pastebin.com/YpqGSJ2E

Comment: mkstemp: No such file or directory